# Default RESTful CakePHP routing gives Missing Controller Method error

Tags: php, cakephp, rest

I am following this tutorial http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html to get up and running with REST in my CakePHP application.

I have added the following to my routes.php file:

```
Router::mapResources(array('fantasyPicks', 'fantasyPlayers'));
Router::parseExtensions();
```

In each of my controllers, I have included the RequestHandler component and also setContent to json in the beforeFilter() callback.  It looks something like this:

```
class FantasyPicksController extends AppController {
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json','text/x-json');
    $this->layout = 'json/default';
}

public function index() {
    $fantasyPicks = $this->FantasyPick->find('all');
    $this->set('json', $fantasyPicks);
    $this->render('/json/data');
}
...
```

My json/data view simply echos json_encode:

```
<?php echo json_encode($json); ?>
```

After all of this, navigating to /fantasyPicks/view/1 works as expected.  However, /fantasyPicks/1 is giving me the following error:

```
Missing Method in FantasyPicksController
Error: The action 1 is not defined in controller FantasyPicksController

Error: Create FantasyPicksController::1() in file: app\Controller\FantasyPicksController.php.

<?php
class FantasyPicksController extends AppController {

    public function 1() {

    }

}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use proper controller naming conventions when accessing the page.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Refer to the URL considerations section.  So you should be going to /fantasy_picks/1 and it will work properly.